# In Groovy, can you use Range as a List?

Tags: groovy

According to the [Groovy docs](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#Collections-Ranges):

> Ranges allow you to create a list of sequential values. These can be used as Lists since Range extends java.util.List.

However, in my case I need the List to end up as a String, including the square brackets. I tried the following:

```
def myRange = 1..5
def myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
// this passes
assert myRange == myList
// both of the following fail!
assert myRange.toString() == myList.toString()
assert myRange.subList(0, 5).toString() == myList.toString()
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extending something does not mean that its `toString` will be the same.

If you have to get the same output as with a list, try

```
myRange.toList().toString()
```

Or

```
"[${myRange.join(',')}]"
```

Or (adding comment as an easy answer for you)

```
assert (1..5).toListString() == "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"
```

Comment: I should have specified: the first thing I did was look for `.toList()` in the [API](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/index.html?groovy/lang/Range.html). Could not find it there.

Comment: It's added to [Collection](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html). You could use `toListString` as well :-) have fun!